# Script in Bash: Find all files

Tags: bash, find, sort, split

I want to write a script in Bash which finds all files less than 100b in `/etc` directory, splits the results on pages and saves the results to a file.
I tried to use this command:

```
find /etc -size -100c | sort | > results
```

But I don't know how split results on pages.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/562915/edit) your question and add the expected output in it.

Comment: Define what you mean by a "page". Do you just want a gap every 60th line? Headings? Footings? Ten files per paragraph? Numbered lines? Maybe just read the output into LibreOffice and make it a document. BTW, you don't pipe and redirect -- use one of the other.

Comment: Yes i want a gap for example every 60 line.

Comment: @user391209 so you want an empty line inserted after every 60 lines of output?

Comment: The `|` should not precede the `>`. You don't use them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /etc -size -100c | sort |
    awk '{ print; } ! (NR % 60) { printf ("\n\n\n\n\n\n"); }' > result
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you would want a "page". Most programs you could use to read a file will handle this sort of thing for you anyway (`less`, or any other viewer, as well as editors). But if you want it, it's easy enough to do something like this:

```
find /etc -size -100c | sort | 
    perl -ne '$. % 60 == 0 ? print "$_\n" : print' > results
```

The `$.` is a special variable that holds the current line number. So the code above will print the current line followed by a newline (`print "$_\n")` when the currently line number (`$.`) modulo 60 is 0, and the current line alone when it is not. The result is a blank line added every 60 lines.

Or, slightly less verbosely:

```
find /etc -size -100c | sort | perl -pe 'print "\n" if $. % 60 == 0' > results
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solutions.
I have one more question. How to insert numbers 1,2,3.... in breaks

Comment: @user391209 you can do `find /etc -size -100c | sort | perl -pe 'print ++$c . "\n" if $. % 60 == 0' > results`. But please don't do this: when you ask a question, make sure it is actually the whole question you need to ask. If you then need something else, please ask a new question instead.